# exit not defined when compile python to binary using pyinstaller on linux

Tags: python, string, compilation, exit, pyinstaller

I have a socket server python script and it runs good on linux, but when compiled to binary on Linux using pyinstaller, it runs into wired situations says

```
File "<string>", line 426, in <module>
File "<string>", line 49, in __init__
NameError: global name 'exit' is not defined
```

environment:

```
Linux 2.6.32, python2.6.6, pyinstaller 2.0
```

here is a simple test script that could recreate this error

program:

```
exit.__class__
```

compile commands:

```
pyinstaller.py -F --noconsole --out=/output_folder/ /source/path
```

which expect to print out:

```
<class 'site.Quitter'>
```

hope someone could give me a clue, a shared library thing?

Answer (score 2):

solved, explicitly use sys.exit(1) to skip this.